# What exactly is member(b,X)?

Tags: prolog

Today I came across this query:

```
?- member(b,X).
```

The program was:

```
member(X,[X|_]).   
member(X,[_|T]) :- 
    member(X,T),
    !.
```

When I ran the query, I got these answers:

```
?- member(b,X).
X = [b|_G1560] ;
X = [_G1559, b|_G1563].
```

What exactly is that? What does this query do?

Comment: The cut (`!`) in the recursive clause is a very bad idea.

Comment: How can I stop the recursion otherwise?

Comment: You need a clause for an empty `X`.

Comment: @Barmar, something like `member(X,[]):- fail.` ?

Comment: It's been about 25 years since I've written any Prolog, but that looks right.

Comment: `member(b, X)` is true if `b` is an element in the list `X`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query `member(b,X)` generates lists containing `b`. As the second argument is not instantiated, you have a (theoretically) infinite number of solutions. The first solution will have `b` in the first position, the second solution will have `b` in the second position and so on. Moreover, if you look closely to any of the solutions, you see that it represents any list with a `b` on that position. For example, the first solution is `[b| _]`. As the list tail is not instantiated (see the `member/2` predicate base case), this solution unifies with any list with `b` in the head position.

If you want to make the `member/2` deterministic, i.e. if you want to use the predicate only to check if a term is a member of a list, you will need to add a cut in the base clause, not in the recursive clause as @false noted:

```
member(Head, [Head| _]) :-
    !.
member(Head, [_| Tail]) :-
    member(Head, Tail).
```

The resulting predicate is usually named `memberchk/2` and available as such as a library predicate.